# Had list of values which contain datatime.datetime() values text file so I want to iterate through list of values and print values line by line python

Tags: python-3.x

I have list in the  format as shown below in a text file:

`[(1, datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 18, 2, 18, 35, 93000), '226', '{string\:some text}', 'something@something.com'), (2, datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 18, 2, 18, 35, 93000), '227', '{string\:some text}', 'something@something.com'), ...]`

I'm using `ast.literal_eval` to format it to list:
But I'm getting errors in the output due to `datetime` values in the list, so any can help out to me to format `datetime` values to string and print line by line

```
import ast
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as SqlList:
    L = SqlList.read()
List = ast.literal_eval(L)
for A in List:
    print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ast.literval_eval` you can use `eval` with the `datetime` module passed in as a global variable.

Add:

```
import datetime
```

Then change:

```
List = ast.literal_eval(L)
```

to:

```
List = eval(L, {'datetime': datetime})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked now it can able take the inputs

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)